# Use a script to export database Schema and Data into SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a means to programmatically pass in a Database name and have it return the Schema and Data as a SQL file.  We work with several clients who have complex database configurations and we would like to be able to back up those configurations for our records.  The people doing the backups would not know how to use a tool such as SQL Server Manager, as well the chance of producing erroneous SQL files is higher.

Comment: MS SQL would be the database I would be running the script against.

Comment: Why do you need the data returned as well.. The file could be in terabytes... Or is just the schema + database objects enough?

Comment: I will be modifying the script to only include tables which contain minimal data.  The databases we build are more for configuration than data storage. The data these servers store is time series through a historical collections system and all data is saved into a dat file with its points. So there really is no massive data being stored.